# Localtunnel gem / Net::SSH not working

Tags: net-ssh, localtunnel

As per the instructions at http://progrium.com/localtunnel/ and elsewhere:

```
gem install localtunnel
localtunnel -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 3000
```

I get the error:

```
/path/to/gems/net-ssh-2.6.7/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:103:in `block in next_packet': connection closed by remote host (Net::SSH::Disconnect)
```

It does not matter whether I include the key or not, or try different port numbers i.e.

```
localtunnel 3000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

localtunnel has been down for a while now

- https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel/issues/105
- https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel/issues/98

Try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) instead. (The two projects are supposedly merging in the near future.)